# Paket error: "Package was referenced, but it was not found in the paket.lock file"

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, paket

When using [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/), how to fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

The easiest way to fix this error is to delete the file `paket.lock`, and force Paket to regenerate this file using `Tools >> Paket >> Update`:

[image]

You can watch the `paket.lock` being regenerated in the `Output` view:
[image]

Ensure that these files have already been committed into source control, so you can roll back if need be.

### Option 2

Alternatively, you can do exactly what is says: edit the `paket.lock` file to include the file that is referenced in `paket.references`, but not in `paket.lock`.

### Docs on paket.lock file

For more information, see [docs on the Paket Lock File](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/lock-file.html).

Comment: Might be worth noting that Option 1 will result in new versions of all dependencies, where the dependencies have been updated to a new version(s) since the last generation of the paket.lock file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused when you add a package reference to your project's `paket.references` file, but you have not actually added the dependency to your `paket.dependencies` file.  To resolve this, add the dependency to `paket.dependencies` and then run `paket.exe install`.  This will add the new dependency to `paket.lock` and leave the existing dependency versions as they were.

If you are using paket groups, don't forget that the dependency will need to be added once for each group that wishes to reference it.